# How to move annotation with animation in mapbox map?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am using mapbox map in my iOS app. I added annotation in mapbox map by using this class **MGLPointAnnotation**.

Now the problem is i am unable to change its location. This is how i changing annotation location. But it is not moving. I need to remove first old one and again need to add new annotation but i don't want to do this.Please let me know how can i do this.

```
car.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
```

**I want the movement of annotation when location changed of annotation with smooth animation.**

Also when there is a change in location i'm changing center of my mapbox map with camera. Let me know i am doing right or not.

```
// Optionally set a starting point.
bMbMapView.setCenter(cord, zoomLevel: 7, direction: bearing, animated: true)     
bMbMapView.setDirection(bearing, animated: true)

// Create a camera that rotates around the same center point, rotating 180°.
// `fromDistance:` is meters above mean sea level that an eye would have to be in order to see what the map view is showing.
let camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: cord, fromDistance: 1000, pitch: 7, heading: 90)

 // Animate the camera movement over 5 seconds.
 bMbMapView.setCamera(camera, withDuration: 1, animationTimingFunction: CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MGLAnnotationView is a UIView, so you should be able to animate changes with Core Animation: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/8378#issuecomment-287910768

Another option is to use a style source and layer, then update the source using a timer. This would likely be less smooth than using an animated annotation view.

Comment: but the problem is by setting new coordinate, the annotation location is not changing. And my object is already from subclass MGLPointAnnotation. Anything wrong i am doing ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya Did you manage to get it working? I am also looking for same kind of feature to add to my iOS project.